# What does reorder() function do in Joomla?

Tags: php, joomla

What does `reorder()` function do in Joomla? I have a statement for a function of menu `copy` in administrator code for menu as:

```
$curr->reorder( 'menutype = '.$this->_db->Quote($curr->menutype).' AND parent = '.(int) $curr->parent );
```

As I have executed this code, it has reordered my id to any other position. I just need to know is this `reorder()` function an inbuilt function of Joomla? If yes, what and how does it do what it has done to my ids?

I am a newbie to Joomla. Please help.

Edit: How can I get the the reordered output just after calling the function?

Comment: "reorder" as in http://docs.joomla.org/JTable/reorder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `reorder()` function is of Joomla and re-orders ids with respect to any child menu items.

Comment: @Sarfraz How can i get the the reordered output just after calling the function?

Comment: Take a look at the code in list.php after the snippet you've posted. `MenusHelper::cleanCache();` Next time te data will be accessed the associated cache will be empty and the re-ordered data will be retrieved from the database.

Comment: @VOLKERK NOT LIKE THAT, I need to print_r or echo out the values directly after the call of reorder function..

Comment: Is changing the "vanilla" reorder() function an option?

Comment: I meant: Would you consider changing the code of function reorder() in libraries/joomla/database/table.php to be an option? All the values you want are "there", but they are simply not returned to the caller. Wouldn't be too difficult. But then you have a custom code base that may come back at you when you update to another joomla version.